# Why do I have different output between a terminal and a file when forking?

Tags: c, fork

I'm learning to work with `fork()`, and I have some questions.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
   int i;

   for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
      printf("%d", i);

      if((i%2)==0)
         if(fork())
            fork();
   }
}
```

When I output to a terminal, I get the result I expect (i.e.: `0,1,1,1,2,2,2,...`). But when I output to a file, the result is completely different:

- Case 1: (output to terminal, e.g.: `./a.out`):

  Result is: `0,1,1,1,2,2,2,...`
- Case 2: (output to file, e.g.: `./a.out > output_file`)

  Result is: `0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,...`

Why it is like this?

Comment: What do you mean with "completely different"? Do you understand multiprocessing, that multiple processes are working at the same time?

Comment: What is the different result?

Comment: We need more code. How are you writing to your file? What is the output that shows on the file?

Comment: @TheCapn, I've added requested information to the questing text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you output to a file, the stdio library automatically block-buffers the outbound bits.

When a program calls `exit(2)` or returns from `main(),` any remaining buffered bits are flushed.

In a program like this that doesn't generate much output, *all* of the I/O will occur after the return from `main(),` when the destination is not a tty. This will often change the pattern and order of I/O operations all by itself.

In this case, the result is further complicated by the series of `fork()` calls. This will duplicate the partially filled and as-yet-unflushed I/O buffers in each child image.

Before a program calls `fork(),` one might first flush I/O using fflush(3). If this flush is not done, then you may want all processes except one (typically: the children) to `_exit(2)` instead of `exit(3)` or return from `main(),` to prevent the same bits from being output more than once. (_exit(2) just does the exit system call.)

Comment: Where I can find more detailed information about things you're explained. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `man 2 _exit; man 2 fork; man 3 exit; man 3 stdio; man 3 fflush` and perhaps http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ForkExecProcesses.html

Answer (score 5):

The `fork()` inside `if` block in your program is executed **twice**, because once fork is successful, the program is controlled by two processes(**child** and **parent** processes).So `fork()` inside `if` block, is executed by both child and parent processes. So it will have different output than expected since it is controlled by two different process and their **order of execution** is not known. ie. either child or parent may execute first after each `fork()`

For the difference in behaviour between the output and the file. this is the reason.

The contents you write to the buffer(to be written to `file(disk)` eventually) is not guaranteed to be written to the file (disk) immediatley. It is mostly flushed to the disk only after the execution of **main()** is **complete**. Whereas, it is output to **terminal**, during the execution of **main()**.

Before writing to file in disk, the `kernel` actually copies the data into a buffer and later in the background, the kernel gathers up all of the dirty buffers, sorts them optimally and writes them out to file(disk).This is called **writeback**. It also allows the **kernel** to defer writes to more **idle** periods and batch many **writes together**.

To avoid such behaviour, it is always good to have three different condition checks in program using `fork()`

```
int pid;
if((pid = fork()) == -1 )
{ //fork unsuccessful 
 }
else if ( pid > 0)
{ //This is parent
 }
else
{//This is child
 }
```

Comment: Can you please clarify how `fork` inside `if` executed twice. I think child will not execute `fork` it will receive result of `fork`, and starts execution from first statement after `fork`.

Answer (score 2):

buffered streams can produce some strange results sometimes... especially when you have multiple processes using the same buffered stream. Force the buffer to be [flushed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) and you'll see different results:

```
int main()
{
   int i;
   FILE * fd = fopen(yourfile, "w");
   for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
      fprintf(fd, "%d", i);
      fflush(fd);
      if((i%2)==0)
         if(fork())
            fork();
   }
}
```

Also, for your debugging purposes, it might be nice to dump the process' IDs so you can see which process spawns which, and have a better idea of what's going on. [`getpid()`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc/lr2/getpid.htm) can help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do I have different output between a terminal and a file when
>   forking?

C standard library functions use internal buffering for speed up. Most implementations use fully buffered IO for file streams, line buffered for stdin/stdout and unbuffered for stderr.

So your problem can be solved in number of ways:

1. Use explicit buffer flush before fork via `fflush(3)`
2. Set buffer type manually via `setvbuf(3)`
3. Use `write(2)` instead of stdlib's `printf(3)`
4. Output to `stderr` by default via `fprintf(3)` *****
5. Exit with `_exit(2)` in forked processes instead of `exit(3)` ******

Last two may not work as expected if:
* your implementation does not use unbuffered writes to stderr by default (Which is required by ISO C)
** you have written more than default buffer size in child and if was automatically flushed.

**PS**. Yet again, if you need deeper knowledge of standard library functions and buffering I recommend reading [Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment (2nd Edition) by W. Richard Stevens and Stephen A. Rago](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201433079).

**PPS**. btw, your question is a very popular interview question for C/C++ programmer position.